# Janino scriptella with the use of array List

Tags: java, scriptella, janino

I am using trying to copying column of an oracle with scriptella , i would like to insert them into an ArrayList combining scriptella and janino , in order to use them and compare them later ,

here what i did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>
        test script Pour table article
    </description>
    <connection id="in" driver="oracle"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" user="IPTECH" password="IPTECH" />

    <connection id="out" driver="postgresql"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gemodb" user="postgres"
        password="maher" />
    <connection id="janino" driver="janino" />

    <query connection-id="in">
        select code,libelle from TMP_STRUCTURE;
        <script connection-id="janino">
            import java.util.*;
            import java.io.*;
            Boolean result=false;
            ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList <String>();
            String code =get("code").toString();
            obj.add(code);
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```

I got the following issue

```
Unable to parse document: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/MHT/eclipse-workspace/Scriptella/test.xml; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 5; The element type "String" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</String>".
```

Any help would bbe appreciated

Comment: Open `test.xml`, located in the `C:/Users/MHT/eclipse-workspace/Scriptella/` directory on your computer, with a code editor. Scroll down to line number `23`. Check that, what I assume to be, the opening `<String>` tag on line number `23` has a closing `String` tag (`</String>`).

Comment: The problem that the scriptella consider as for any opening < should be a closning , but here i am using <string> as a type not a balise ? i would like to ask if there is another solution to work with ArrayList via scriptella and janino  , Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the, properly formatted, contents of `test.xml`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly the code i provided , is the content of the test.xml file

Answer (score 1):

you must replace

```
 ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList <String>();
```

with

```
 java.util.ArrayList &lt; String> obj = new ArrayList java.util.ArrayList &lt; String>();
```